# No local package in tlmgr while I can compile in winedt in windows

Tags: texlive, windows, environment-variables

Last week, I change my user name. Then things happen. And I add environment path

`C:\texlive\2014\bin\win32;`

But still cannot find any local information in tlmgr. How can I solve this problem

[image: http://i730.photobucket.com/albums/ww309/ytyyutianyun/Ashampoo_Snap_20141115_13h09m30s_001_TeXLiveManager2014.jpg]

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about what you mean by "any local information". E.g., are you referring to packages installed in the localtexmf tree?

Comment: @Mico, _**1**_. I mean `Local rev.(ver)`. That I cannot update as usual 
_**2**_. No program information when I search in `windows search`, whereas in the past, I can only type `tex live manager` and then run. But now, I need to go to the directory to run `tlmgr`